# How to implement library calendar view

Tags: android, kotlin, calendarview

I am using [this](https://github.com/JonasWanke/com.jonaswanke.calendar) library to make calendar app similar to google calendar week view calendar. I read all documentation and added implementation `'com.jonaswanke.calendar:calendar:0.1.1'` in `build.gradle`, but when I add calendar view to `activity_mail.xml`

```
<com.jonaswanke.calendar.CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:range="week" />
```

following exception crashed my app on app start.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 13101
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.jonaswanke.calendar.CalendarView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4074)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.jonaswanke.calendar.CalendarView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.jonaswanke.calendar.CalendarView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:864)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1016)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:971)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1133)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1094)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:692)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:536)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8085)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8073)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3868)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4074)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlinx/coroutines/experimental/CoroutineDispatcher;
        at com.jonaswanke.calendar.CalendarView.<init>(CalendarView.kt:495)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.jonaswanke.calendar.CalendarView.<init>(CalendarView.kt:32)
        at com.jonaswanke.calendar.CalendarView.<init>(Unknown Source:6)
            ... 28 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CoroutineDispatcher
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 31 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/coroutines/experimental/AbstractCoroutineContextElement;
            ... 31 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.coroutines.experimental.AbstractCoroutineContextElement" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-_1QFEnFxaCJxdEfjNQvp0g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-_1QFEnFxaCJxdEfjNQvp0g==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /prets/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:209)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 31 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13101 SIG: 9
```

In MainActivity.kt file I only added:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    calendar.eventRequestCallback = {
        populate(it)
    }
}

@Suppress("MagicNumber")
private fun populate(week: Week, force: Boolean = false) {
    if (!force && calendar.cachedEvents.contains(week))
        return

    val events = mutableListOf<Event>()
    for (i in 0..15) {
        val id = nextId++.toString()
        val start = week.start + abs(random.nextLong()) % DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS
        events.add(BaseEvent(
                id,
                id,
                (random.nextInt() or 0xFF000000.toInt()) and 0x00202020.inv(),
                start,
                start + abs(random.nextLong()) % (DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS / 8)))
    }
    for (i in 0..3) {
        val id = nextId++.toString()
        val start = week.start + abs(random.nextLong()) % DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS
        events.add(BaseEvent(
                id,
                id,
                (random.nextInt() or 0xFF000000.toInt()) and 0x00202020.inv(),
                start,
                start + abs(random.nextLong()) % (DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS * 7),
                true))
    }
    calendar.setEventsForWeek(week, events)
}
```

But even without this code app still crashes.

Comment: me too getting this error. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @QadirHussain only useful library / sample project I found is this: https://github.com/jignesh13/googlecalendar

Answer (score 1):

This is an old library that was built using experimental Kotlin features. It hasn't been maintained for two years. I tried for 20 minutes to get it to compile. It's just not worth it. I suggest using one of the several other Android CalendarView libraries out there:

https://github.com/search?q=android+calendarview

This one looks particularly promising:

https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView

Comment: Thank your for suggestion but [link](https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView) is not what I am looking for. I am looking for calendar that can show days in week and for each day its events, something like google daily or week view